# matplotlib: Plot 2D scatter plot for multidimensional dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have the following data frame which shows the multiple variables including year range, sex, nationality and sum count of people.

```
+---------+---+---+----------+
| range   |Sex|NOC|sum(count)|
+---------+---+---+----------+
|2000-2020|  M|SUR|        13|   
|2000-2020|  M|SRI|        33|   
|1940-1960|  F|YUG|        86|    
|1980-2000|  F|IND|        54|    
|1900-1920|  M|GBR|      1636|    
|2000-2020|  M|AFG|        13| 
+---------+---+---+----------+
```

I wanted to plot the following scatter plot in matplotlib or seaborn. How can I do this

[image]

Comment: You should give more details and a code example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to unstack `sex` column to get two more columns: `M` and `F`. Dirty example:

```
>>> df_ = df.set_index(['year', 'noc', 'sex']).unstack().reset_index()
>>> df_.columns = [''.join(col).strip() for col in df_.columns.values]
```

Then you can use seaborn:

```
>>> sb.scatterplot(x='sumM', y='sumF', hue='year', data=df)
```